# value_counts result - splitting it by an additional column?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

value_counts doesn't allow me to further break it down by an additional column. Basically, what I am trying to do is recreate something like this in pandas:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uys4i.jpg

The data is here https://data.seattle.gov/Community/Seattle-Pet-Licenses/jguv-t9rb

For the sake of simplicity, at the moment I just want to split the data into 3 columns:
Name, Cat (count of name), Dog (count of name).

I've been looking around and have tried groupby and pivot_tables but don't think I understand it enough.

What I've tried:

```
`animal_names.groupby(['animals_name', 
'species']).size().sort_values(ascending=False)`
```

which returns:

```
`animals_name                    species
Lucy                            Dog        335
Charlie                         Dog        306
Bella                           Dog        248
Luna                            Dog        242
Daisy                           Dog        217
                                          ... 
Mossi                           Dog          1
Mosses                          Dog          1
Mossberg                        Dog          1
Moska                           Dog          1
"Luci" Lucia Rosalin Wicksugal  Dog          1
Length: 16749, dtype: int64`
```

and I've tried:

```
`animal_names.pivot_table(
    index=['animals_name', 'species'],
    values='primary_breed',
    aggfunc='count')
`
```

Which doesn't return the desirable either.

Is there a way to do something as simple as 
    `dataframe['animals_name'].value_counts()` and then split the result by another column (in this case, species)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close.

```py
df=animal_names.pivot_table( index='animals_name', columns='species', aggfunc='count')
```

Values is optional, to help you remember how pivot work, look at you final tables.

- What are the elements on the first column? It's your index, so here is animal_name.
- What are columns names? Each species.
- Values are simply deduce by this the above parameters, that why it's optional

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below :

```
df = pd.pivot_table(data1,index="Animal's Name",columns = "Species",aggfunc = np.count_nonzero)
```

Here the data1 contains two columns, Animal's Name and Species.

The output will display the name and the counts on the respective species.

There will be NAN values and you can replace it with zero.